# belongs_to with :conditions in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, Users and Accounts:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account, :conditions=>proc{" company_account = #{self.company_user} "}
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

In Rails 3 `belongs_to` and `:conditions=>` works fine, but in Rails 4 I read this options is not valid.

I tried `belongs_to :account, -> {where company_account: self.company_user}` but I get error `undefined method`*`company_user`*

How can I solve this in Rails 4?

Comment: I'm guessing your copied your syntax incorrectly for the question? It should read as, `belongs_to :account, -> { where(company_account: self.company_user) }`, right?

Comment: Thanks Chris Peters for your answer, I copied the syntax from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference #4.1.3 "Scopes for belongs_to"; I will try your answer.

Comment: Same error "undefined method 'company_user' "

Comment: Is `company_user` defined on `user`? What is that supposed to return? It's not obvious by looking at your code.

Comment: Yes, `company_user` is defined on `user`; I need to validate that the company for the account that is asigned to the user is iqual at user's company.

Comment: Can you update the code in your question to include this `company_user` method? Or is it a column in your `users` table? If so, what's the value when it throws this error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, by using a composed primary key in my Account model.

For this, I used [this gem](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
belongs_to :account, -> { where("company_account_id = ?", self.send(:company_user).id) }
```

Comment: Bratsche, I tried your example, this got me "SyntaxError..."

Comment: Sorry about that. I made some edits to it, see if this helps any.