# Rails: belongs_to with conditions/scope throwing syntax error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, conditional-associations

I want to pick companies that are owned. I tried multiple combinations, *new, rails 3, old school,...* all of which are throwing the same syntax error `unexpected '\n', expecting =>`

```
belongs_to :from, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'from_id', -> { where owned: true }
belongs_to :from, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'from_id', -> { where(owned: true) }
belongs_to :from, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'from_id', -> { where(:owned => true) }
belongs_to :from, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'from_id', condition: { where(:owned => true) }
```

Someone seems to have asked it 3 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24275835/3125070), but there seems to be no definitive answer! Is there any other way? Google's not returning relevant results for `belongs_to with conditions` or `with scope`

I need to do exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29024881/3125070), but that exact answer's throwing syntax error too...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> unexpected '\n', expecting =>

You need to *switch* the order of `scope` with `options`

```
# File activerecord/lib/active_record/associations.rb, line 1514
def belongs_to(name, scope = nil, options = {})
  reflection = Builder::BelongsTo.build(self, name, scope, options)
  Reflection.add_reflection self, name, reflection
end
```

As you can see, the `scope` should be the *second parameter* and `options` should be the *third parameter*.

This should work

```
belongs_to :from, -> { where owned: true }, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: 'from_id'
```